# Carousel Auto Slide not working ? what is the issue, help me to slove the issue?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel, carousel-slider

> Carousel Autoslide not working. ?
>
> > I have tried using bootstrap manually it's working, the only problem I am facing is auto-slide-doesn't work.
> >
> > > Bootstrap Carousel Auto Slide not working? what is the issue, help me to solve the issue?
> > >
> > > > not got solved

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators"> 

    <li data-bs-target="#carouselindicator" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" ></li>
    <li data-bs-target="#carouselindicator" data-bs-slide-to="1"  ></li>
    <li data-bs-target="#carouselindicator" data-bs-slide-to="2"  ></li>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <div class="carousel-item active" >

        <div class="container">

        <div class=" rowcarousel d-flex row">

            <div class="img-responsive  carousel-lh-item col-lg-4 justify-content-start">

                <img src="https://www.puthuvaravu.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/IMG-20190716-WA0006.jpg" style="border-radius: 50%; border: 3px solid royalblue;" width="90%">

                <p style="text-align: center;">Mylsamy Annadurai</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <p>Mylswamy Annadurai, byname Moon Man, (born July 2, 1958, Kodhawady, Tamil Nadu, India),
                         Indian aerospace engineer who held a number of posts with the Indian Space 
                         Research Organisation (ISRO),</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- second slide -->

    <div class="carousel-item " >

        <div class="container">

        <div class=" rowcarousel d-flex row">

            <div class="img-responsive  carousel-lh-item py-1 col-lg-4 justify-content-start">

                <img src="https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/kerala/gt264u/article32329021.ece/alternates/FREE_435/TH11KRANAMBINARAYANAN-1" style="border-radius: 50%; border: 3px solid royalblue;" width="95%">

                <p style="text-align: center;">Nambi Narayanan</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <p>S. Nambi Narayanan (born 12 December 1941) is an Indian aerospace engineer who worked at the Indian Space Research Organisation (ISRO).</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- third slide -->

    
    <div class="carousel-item " >

        <div class="container">

        <div class=" rowcarousel d-flex row">

            <div class="img-responsive  carousel-lh-item col-lg-4 justify-content-start">

                <img src="https://track2traininginstitute.files.wordpress.com/2021/07/apj.jpg" style="border-radius: 50%; border: 3px solid royalblue;" width="90%">

                <p style="text-align: center;">A. P. J. Abdul Kalam</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <p>Avul Pakir Jainulabdeen Abdul Kalam was an Indian aerospace scientist who served as the 11th President of India from 2002 to 2007.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

> Carousel Autoslide not working. ?
>
> > I have tried using bootstrap manually it's working, the only problem I am facing is auto-slide-doesn't work.
> >
> > > Bootstrap Carousel Auto Slide not working? what is the issue, help me to solve the issue?
> > >
> > > > not got solved

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
data-bs-ride="carousel"
```

to the first ol.
So:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators" data-bs-ride="carousel">
```

that tells bootstrap to autocycle the carousel as soon as the page loads

if it doesn´t work, try replacing the ol with a div